Getting decimal value from division
I am trying to get a decimal value with the code:
declare @percents decimal(16, 2) = convert(decimal(16, 2), 100);

declare @fifteenPercent decimal(16,2) = convert(decimal(16,2), @fifteen) * @percents / convert(decimal(16, 2), @total);

Both @total and @fifteen variables are integers. What I get is a whole number in following select
select 
    '1-15: (' + trim(str(@fifteen)) +') ' + trim(str(@fifteenPercent)) + '%' as ratingB

I get 1-15: (38230) 7%
I want 1-15: (38230) 7.28%
I converted all variables to decimal(16,2) and still get an integer value

str(@fifteenPercent) read what STR does if nothing is passed in second and third parameter

You should be able to just use CONCAT() with no trimming etc... SELECT CONCAT ('1-15: (',  @fifteen, ') ' , @fifteenPercent,  '%') as ratingB

FORMAT(@YourNumber, 'P2')

thank you for suggestions. I found the answer myself
The point is to really use FORMAT() funciton, but the percentage needs to be divided by 100, before formating.
format(@fiteenPercentage / 100, 'P2')

If divided, the outcome is

26-50: (343474) 3,37 %

If not the outcome is

26-50: (343474) 337,00 %

which means the function needs to work with number between 0 and 1

in conclusion the numeric format needs to lookl like this 'fromat(15/100, 'P2')' or 'fromat(0.15, 'P2')'
